Is every finite dimensional (semisimple) Hopf algebra isomorphic to its opposite?
For any finite dimensional Hopf algebra $A$, the opposite Hopf algebra $A^{\mathrm{op}}$ has the same coalgebra structure as $A$ but has the opposite product defined as
$$a\cdot_{\mathrm{op}}b:=b\cdot a.$$
The unit, counit, and coproduct of $A^{\mathrm{op}}$ is the same as that of $A$, but the antipode of $A^{\mathrm{op}}$ is the inverse of that of $A$. It is straightforward to check $A^{\mathrm{op}}$ is also a Hopf algebra.
Question: Is it always true that $A^{\mathrm{op}}$ is isomorphic to $A$ as a Hopf algebra?
Note that it is always true that $A$ is isomorphic to $A^{\mathrm{op},\mathrm{cop}}$ (whose product and copropuct are both opposite to that of $A$), since the antipode provides an isomorphism. So the answer is yes for cocommutative Hopf algebras (e.g. group algebras). I'm happy to add more conditions, e.g. semisimplicity, but I'm also interested in the more general setting, e.g., when $A$ is infinite dimensional.

Let $A$ be a Hopf algebra with comultiplication $\Delta$, counit $\epsilon$ and antipode $S$. Then as you said, the opposite algebra $A^{op}$ is a Hopf algebra with coalgebra structure $\Delta$ and $\epsilon$ and antipode $S^{-1}$, if the latter exists.
If $f:A\to B$ is a bialgebra map between Hopf algebras with antipode $S_A$ and $S_B$ respectively, then $f\circ S_A = S_B \circ f$.
Hence, if there exists a bialgebra map $f:A\to A^{op}$, then $f\circ S = S^{-1}\circ f$.
Using that $f$ is a coalgebra map, i.e. $\sum_{f(a)} f(a)_{(1)}\otimes f(a)_{(2)} = \sum_{a} f(a_{(1)})\otimes f(a_{(2)})$ we have
$$ \epsilon(a) = \epsilon(f(a)) = \sum_{f(a)} S^{-1}(f(a)_{(1)})\cdot^{op} f(a)_{(2)} = \sum_{a}f(a_{(2)}) S^{-1}(f(a_{(1)})) = f\left(\sum_a a_{(2)}S(a_{(1)})\right).$$
If $f$ is injective, then $\sum_a a_{(2)}S(a_{(1)})=\epsilon(a)$ must hold for any $a\in A$. Hence, $S^2=id$ (see for instance Theorem 1.5 in Schneider's lecture notes).
Thus, if $S^2\neq id$, then there cannot exist an injective bialgebra map between $A$ and $A^{op}$. A class of Hopf algebras with $S^2\neq id$ is given by the Taft algebras, with its smallest member the Sweedler algebra.
